# Using shared database authentication settings for organization environment?

Tags: qgis-3

My company is willing to share common QGIS3 configuration parameters between its users (ie. proxy configuration, WFS/WMS connections definitions, database connection definitions).

For doing this, the documentation explains [how to use a global settings file](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#deploying-qgis-within-an-organization) (ie. a customized *qgis_global_settings.ini* file), which works perfectly fine. For the case of database connections (Postgis & Oracle in our case), I configured the connections this way:

```
[PostgreSQL]
connections\myconnection\service=
connections\myconnection\host=my_company_database_host
connections\myconnection\port=5432
connections\myconnection\database=my_database
connections\myconnection\username=xxxxxxx
connections\myconnection\password=yyyyyyyy
connections\myconnection\authcfg=
connections\myconnection\saveUsername=true
connections\myconnection\savePassword=true
(...)
```

This raises 2 problems:

- 'username' and 'password' are plaintext/unencrypted.
- for this to work, I had to switch 'saveUsername' and 'savePassword' to TRUE, because we want to avoid our users the burden of entering the credentials by themselves.

I believe that *saveUsername* and *savePassword* will save the credentials in any project file using this database connection. This is a problem if the project files are sent outside the company.

Another approach:

QGIS3 provides an [authentication manager](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/index.html). It stores encrypted passwords fields, in a sqlite database file (*qgis-auth.db*). My understanding is that, in some way, this auth database can be linked with the above configuration file using the *authcfg* field.

Is there any way to use the *qgis-auth.db* in an organization environnement ?

For example,

- sharing a *qgis-auth.db* file on network
- using the Python API to fill a local *qgis-auth.db* with default credentials when deploying QGIS for the first time

Comment: I'd also like to know how to best share the qgis-auth.db file so that 50+ users can read from the same file, instead of me needing to send a modified qgis-auth.db file to 50 users.